# How to remove new files from git repo safely

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I added some new files to a local copy of a Github repo and accidentally ran `git add *` and `git commit`, but not `git push`.

I think the new files should only be on my local copy of the repo. How do I safely *remove* those files from the **next** `git push` command. I want to keep the files locally, but **not include** them in the *next push*.

What is the best way to remove them from git, but leave them in place on my hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following:

`git reset --soft HEAD~1`

`--soft` ensures that those files aren't deleted from your hard drive.

`~1` refers to the latest commit.
You can also do the same for the last `n` commits by using `HEAD~n`

If you don't want those files to ever be pushed to your remote repository, consider creating a `.gitignore` and adding those files to it.

You can read more about `.gitignore` [here.](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: This is mostly correct asuming the most recent commit (and *only* the most recent commit) contains the files.  If the files are particularly sensitive, then it is worth noting that this does *not* remove them from your local repo.  They wouldn't be reachable from any ref, and you generally wouldn't expect git to transmit them during a push, but I'm not aware of anything in the docs that guarantees it won't; so for example if there are passwords involved, it might be worth some additional steps to properly sanitize the local repo.  Those procedures are covered in answers to existing questions

Comment: what does the ~1 do in the command above?

Comment: @DonaldS I have updated the answer, you can have a look

Answer (score -1):

I think `git reset --soft HEAD~1` should do the trick.

Comment: `HEAD` is the state of the most recent commit.  Since they've already committed, this won't work.